# How to detect that a regex that matches and capture has not found a match

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have the following javascript code that uses regex to match if a certain string contains a phone number in international fomart and capture the number

```
var myString1 = "some other string +123456789 some other string";
var myString2 = "some other string 123456789 some other string";

var regex = new RegExp("\\+(\\d+)");
var number = myString1.match(regex)[1];

if (typeof (number) == "string") {
  // some positive actions
}
else {
  // some negative actions
}
```

The code works perfectly if there is a match and for the code above, the if statement will return true so **some positive actions** will be executed

The problem is that if the match is not found (e.g when **myString2** is used), the if statement will neither return true nor false meanig **some negative actions** also won't be executed

i have tried

```
if (number == "" || number == null) {
  // some negative actions
}
else {
  // some positive actions
}
```

The else part will work if there is a match but if there is not match it wont detect if there is no match. i have tried printing the datatype of `number` using  `typeof(number)` when `mystring2` is used and it also returns nothing. it is not null or empty

What condition can i use to detect if there is no match

**NB: I must use regex**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because you are getting the second item in the array immediately after calling `match()`. If there is no match, it returns `null`, and thus you get an error.

Instead, first check whether the `match()` method returns an array (either with `Array.isArray()` or simply a `null` check), then get the second item:

```js
var myString1 = "some other string +123456789 some other string";
var myString2 = "some other string 123456789 some other string";

var regex = new RegExp("\\+(\\d+)");
var number = myString2.match(regex);

if (Array.isArray(number)) {
  number = number[1];
  console.log('positive');
} else {
  console.log('negative');
}
```